# Python Logistic Regression Y Value Issues

Tags: python, sklearn-pandas

I'm currently getting a mixture of the following errors:

- ValueError: Unknown label type: 'unknown'
- ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead: array=[0. 0. 0. ... 1. 1. 1.]. Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
- TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

When I search for others who have had the same issue, the answer usually leads me from one of the above errors to another. Below is a screenshot of my code. Lines 7-9 are the solutions I found for my errors that just lead to different errors. Comment out line 8 or 9 or both and it gives you the wrong shape error. Comment out all three and you get the label type unknown error.

For line 7 I have tried bool, int, and float.

[image]

```
df.loc[df['ReAdmis'] == 'No', 'ReAdmis'] = "False"
df.loc[df['ReAdmis'] == 'Yes', 'ReAdmis'] = "True"

log_ra = df['ReAdmis']

print(log_ra.head)
log_ra=log_ra.astype('bool')
# log_ra=log_ra.to_numpy()
log_ra=log_ra.reshape(-1,1)


model = LogisticRegression(solver='liblinear')
logistic_regression = model.fit(df1,log_ra)
model.score(log_ra, df1)
```

I am using masks to convert Yes/No to 1/0 for my Y value, is that what is causing this issue? I found a lot of great articles when I was working on the multiple regression version of this, but it seems like logistic regression is less used and I'm not finding as many helpful articles on it.

Comment: Please provide code as text, not as image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Line 9: In your code, please note that `shape` is a tuple and a property of the `DataFrame` object, i.e., you cannot *call* it but only access it; see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shape.html

Maybe you wanted to use `reshape` there?

Line 7: `astype(float)` changes the type of the columns to `float` (see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html); if you want to replace `Yes` and `No` with `True` and `False` respectively, you could set it as such on line 1 and 2. After that, you can use `df = df.astype(bool)` to set the type to `bool`.

Example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([{"ReAdmis": "No"}, {"ReAdmis": "Yes"}])
>>> df[df["ReAdmis"] == "Yes"] = True
>>> df[df["ReAdmis"] == "No"] = False
>>> # The dtype of the ReAdmins column is object; need to explicitly convert it to bool
>>> df = df.astype(bool)
>>> print(df)
  ReAdmis
0    False
1    True
>>> print(df.dtypes)
ReAdmis    bool
dtype: object
```

Comment: astype only changes type if there is a single data in a cell in that specific column.

Comment: @vagitus Not really sure if we're talking about the same, but the following works perfectly fine (without data): `df_empty = pd.DataFrame({'A' : []}); df_empty = df_empty.astype('int32');`

Comment: Thank you! I still had to convert to numpy as well, but this worked. I had assumed that you could convert 0 and 1 to bool as well, but that doesn't seem to be the case?

Comment: @Chelsea You're very welcome. Regarding the conversion of 0 and 1 to bool I just tried it out and it actually should work: `df[df["ReAdmis"] == "Yes"] = 1; df[df["ReAdmis"] == "No"] = 0; df = df.astype(bool); print(df); print(df.dtypes)`